# Taking log2Ceil of UInt

Tags: scala, chisel

I'm taking log2 of following calculation:

```
tl_out.a.bits.size := log2Ceil(s1_row * s2_column * 4.U)
```

where, s1_row and s2_column are UInt.
I'm getting following error:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to ...rocket-chip/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] ...scala:199:25: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
[error]   (in: Int)Int <and>
[error]   (in: BigInt)Int
[error]  cannot be applied to (chisel3.core.UInt)
[error]         tl_out.a.bits.size := log2Ceil(s1_row * s2_column * 4.U)
[error]                               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

It seems that log2Ceil can not be performed on UInt/SInt. Is there any way to typecast UINT/SInt or alternate method for log2Ceil which can be performed over UInt?
Please assist...

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Is there any easy way to find most significant set bit? in chisel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`log2Ceil()` is a good function to find size of a word. But be aware that it's not "synthesizable" for `UInt()` Wire or Reg. `log2Ceil()` calculation is done once at synthesize time, it's not an hardware function. Then your output signal `tl_out.a.bits.size` will be a constant.

If you want to find the most significant set bit, you should use the hardware functions named `PriorityEncoder(Reverse(s1_row * s2_column * 4.U))`.

The [PriorityEncoder](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.1.6/index.html#chisel3.util.PriorityEncoder$)() return the position of least significant '1' in signal.
And the [Reverse](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.1.6/index.html#chisel3.util.Reverse$)() reverse the bits order in signal.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i was looking for.